# Which metric to use for evaluation of a classifier with imbalanced data?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I am working on a classification problem where the classes are very imbalanced. To handle this issue, I used over-sampling with replacement. (as it is suggested here: http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/
).

Then I divide the data set (the over sampled one) into train and test set and train the naive Bayes algorithm. When I want to test, is it ok to use the accuracy measure. As I understand it for the classes with low samples, I have essntially added copies of the samples. So my test_set contain exact copies of the train set. What about the confusion matrix, what does it mean to use confusion matrix on over sampled data set? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Just a general remark - you cannot learn anything with **single example** in a class. gather **orders of magnitude** more data.

Answer (score 3):

First of all answer one question: **What are you trying to achieve?** In other words - what is your model supposed to do "in the wild". Evaluation metric has to simply answer this question, nothing else. Second of all - **always** first **split** data, then preprocess. This is of crucial importance when you try to replicate some data as you suggest - if you first replicate and then split you might end up having **the same** points in both train and test, which would be horrible for your estimation.

In particular - you are dealing with imbalanced dataset. The main question is **why** is it imbalanced? Is it because **real** data is imbalanced (for example-you are dealing with binary classification with vary rare positive classes) or it is a consequence of some odd way to gather data, which is not really a random sample from the underlying process (for example normally classes are completely balanced, but your labeled dataset is not, since people prefer to label positive samples in your problem). If real data is imbalanced then you **cannot** change balance in the test set, this will completely break any conclusions you will try to draw from the experiments. Test data **has to** be the representative sample of **true data**. You cannot alter it "for your own needs", never. If the later is true - then you can try to alter test to make it more similar to true data (the same argument as before).

What you can do is modify metric to match what you care about (and yes, oversampling test data can achieve the same effect but it is crucial to understand what you do here - you can modify the metric, but you cannot touch test set, if you want to get valid probabilistic reasoning in general). If you just care about a model which has a high probability of correct classification with random data point - use accuracy. If you care more about some class (in imbalanced scenario you often do) - you can always overweight **cost of a mistake** by attaching different cost to FP or FN and compute your own metric based on confusion matrix. Just remember, that if you do use custom metric, you have to "tell"  your model you do that. 90% of classifiers our there assume that you care about accuracy, and they maximize it. If you alter the metric - "naive" application of the classifier again may lead to invalid conclusions (in terms of model selection).

To sum up:

- do not modify distribution of test data (no oversampling!)
- set metric which matches **what you want to learn**
- add this information to your learning scheme (like - attach classes weights for svm, logistic regression etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by  always first split data, and then pr-eprocess? I provided an example of my data in the eidt.

Comment: Think about what would happen if you over-sample before splitting your data (that's the pre-processing you mentioned). Isn't it now possible that you could end up with the same observations in training and test sets, like lejlot mentioned? Do you think that might be a cause for concern about how well the model will generalize to unseen/new data?

Comment: Yes, if I first over-sample and then split the data to train and test I would end up with the same observation in the training and test set which is not what I want. So, I should first split my data , then over-sample the train set and then use the test-set that was obtained before the over-sampling. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What about the classes that I have only one sample from. When I split they would be either in the train set of the test set. If they are in the test set that is ok, i guess since it would test what the algorithm does when it sees unseen data.

Comment: you cannot do *anything* with such data. Literally - nothing (I am omitting here more advanced methods of zero shot learning etc.). You have to gather more data, sorry.

Comment: But I should not remove them, otherwise I am not testing the generalization power of my classifier. Am i right?

Comment: As long as you care about these classes you cannot remove them. Really, there is nothing to do or discuss here - you need to gather way more data to do anything